# Automatically launch an Applescript on a USB when that USB is plugged in?

Tags: applescript

I'm making an application to be stored on a USB. When that USB is plugged in, the app (on the same USB) should automatically search the hard drive for any files with a certain name and transfer them to the USB. I know how to find the files and move them, so what I really need to know is how to automatically run the application. Can anyone help?

Code for finding files if anyone needs it (credit to user Vadian):

```
set startupDisk to POSIX path of (path to startup disk)
set endLocation to POSIX path of ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources")
set filename to "pdffilename.pdf" as string

do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & quoted form of startupDisk & " -0 'kMDItemDisplayName = \"" & filename & "\"' | xargs -0 -J {} cp {} " & quoted form of endLocation
```

Comment: It's possible with `launchd` and a launchd agent monitoring `/Volumes`. By the way to search only on the startup disk you can write `... "mdfind -onlyin /  -0 ... ` and delete the first line.

Comment: There is an app called [EventScripts](https://itunes.apple.com/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12) that could be used to trigger when a USB device is plugged in and or removed. I have not used it before, just aware it exists.

Comment: Are you planning to use the app with the your own Mac(s) or with Macs that don't belong to you?

Comment: Both. I want to be able to find a PDF file with a certain name on any computer and transfer to my USB. I would do it manually, but that takes a while: I would just like to speed it up a bit. If it's not possible with launch agents or third party apps, that's fine. -Thanks

Comment: Would attaching your script as a folder action on /Volumes be sufficient to your needs?

Comment: Maybe? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: For your own Macs you may create a process that a) waits for a (specific) thumb drive to be inserted and b) executes any script that matches your scripts name (myscript.scpt). ## It's not possible to run a script from an external drive automatically without changing a Mac's configuration and/or user interaction. This would obviously be a security threat.